# select specify row using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML table like below:

```
ColA       ColB  ColC ColD ColE ColF
Checked    AAAA  BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE
Unchecked  AAAA  BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE
Checked    AAAA  BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE
Checked    AAAA  BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE
Unchecked  AAAA  BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE
Checked    AAAA  BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE
Checked    AAAA  BBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE
```

ColA is a Check box. I want to get the ColD value of all rows whose ColA is Checked. I want to use the jquery to do it. Does anyone meet it before?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var array_of_the_values = $('table input:checked').map(function() { 
    return $(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text();
  }).get();
```

Comment: Actually, I want to do a minor modification. I can not get the right answer using your code. So I make a little change, I change the parents('tr') to parent().parent()

Answer (score 0):

The no-jQuery solution

```
var inputs = document.getElementById("tableId").getElementsByTagName("input"), input, i = inputs.length;
while (i--){
    input = inputs[i];
    if (input.type == "checkbox" && input.checked){
         console.log(input.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[3].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

This is **guaranteed** to be a lot faster than any of the css-selector methods (and easier to understand).

And a slight rewrite to return an array

```
var array_of_values = (function(table){
    var values = [], inputs = table.getElementsByTagName("input"), i = inputs.length;
    while (i--) 
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) 
            values.push(inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[3].innerHTML);
    return values;
})(document.getElementById("tableId"));
```

Comment: question was explicitly bound to jQuery

Comment: Thats really not a good argument.. Especially since most in here think that javascript == jQuery..

Comment: I would not expect to get eggs if I ask for oranges

Comment: appeal to ridicule.
He asked for neither - he wanted to hit a nail with a clunky sledge when he had a hammer.

Comment: Have to agree with jAndy here - jQuery solution lot less code therefore easier to understand, also less prone to breaking when making changes.

Comment: I'm not fighting that :) But I hate to cater to those who treats jQuery as the 'one and only' - so I offer alternatives that are not bound to any framework. 
As a sidenote: if you break your code when making changes.. well, then you do not know what you are doing..

Comment: thanks you all. Actually, I just want to use the JavaScript. The reason that I bind it to jquery is that it's easier. If non-jquery can also solve this problem, it's also great.

Answer (score 0):

$('table input:checked').parent('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text();